# Confusion with Cauchy sequences in a metric space being called "intrinsically convergent"

Tags: analysis, cauchy-sequences

I'm reading the discussion about convergent sequences defined on a metric space on Simmons "Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis".
The author explains why trivially a convergent sequence
is a Cauchy sequence and shows how because the convergence of a sequence depends not only of the sequence itself but of the nature of the
metric space, a Cauchy sequence in certain metric space may happen to not converge.

Right after that, he says:

> Some writers emphasize the distinction between convergent sequences
> and Cauchy sequences by calling the latter "intrinsically convergent"
> sequences.

The world "intrinsic" means "belonging to or part of the real nature of something/somebody", then isn't saying that Cauchy sequences in a metric space are intrinsically convergent a total mistake ?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the meaning of the phrase (I'm not an native english speaker), but I'm thinking of an *"intrinsical property"* as being something opposite to an *"embedding property"* (for example, a group H is not normal "per se", but with respect to some group that contains it).

Comment: Maybe it‘s just me but that doesn‘t make sense to me either. Also, I have never heard anyone calling Cauchy sequences intrinsically convergent in my mathematical life.

Comment: It would be my guess that the concept is Cauchy sequences are those that "intrinsically" converge in the sense of all getting close to each other.   Whether there is an actual point in the space for them to converge TO is dependent on the space it is in.   Every incomplete space has a unique (up to isomorphism) complete space where you "put in" the missing limit points

Comment: So I've never actually seen this usage, but as a native English speaker I can hack up some rationalizations for it. Here's one: "if you take a convergent sequence and then examine the same sequence of points in a metric space consisting of only those points, equipped with the restriction of the original metric, you get a Cauchy sequence".

Comment: (Cont.) Thus, Cauchiness is the "intrinsic property" of convergent sequences, in the sense that it rather than convergence is what is guaranteed to still be there if you remove the rest of the space. This makes it a property of the sequence "alone" rather than the sequence together with the ambient space. All in all I wouldn't dwell too much on this linguistic distinction.

Comment: I think Ian‘s comment goes to the direction the author is thinking of: Whether a sequence $(a_n)$ converges depends on the space (i.e. is the limit inside the space or not) while whether a sequence $(a_n)$ is Cauchy depends only on $(a_n)$, so it‘s a property intrinsic to the sequence (so intrinsic is targeted at the sequence, not the space).

Comment: (However, of course the $a_n$‘s all need to live in some space, etc etc, so I would just recommend to avoid using this phrase, most people will at first probably not understand what you would mean.)

Comment: Thank you kindly for your comments, it was enlightening to read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Intrinsically convergent” wouldn’t mean literally convergent, because we have a term for that already, “convergent.” So, as a technical term you shouldn’t take “intrinsic” quite so literally.

Not every Cauchy sequence in the rationals converges in the rationals, but they do in the real numbers. So, while these sequences don’t converge in $\mathbb Q,$ there is a sense in which $\mathbb Q$ is “missing points” to cover these cases, and that they really do converge “some place.”

More generally, given a metric space, $(X,d),$ there is a unique space $(\overline X,d’),$ called the completion of $X,$ which contains $X$ and in which all Cauchy sequences converge. $\overline X$ is in some sense a “natural” extension of $X.$

The completion of the rational numbers is the reals.

For another example, if $$X=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2<1\}$$ with the usual Euclidean distance, then the completion is identical to $\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\leq 1\}.$
The Cauchy sequences in $X$ that don’t converge are instead intrinsically converging to the points on the boundary.

So, while a Cauchy sequence in $X$ does not converge, there is a single “natural” extension of $X$ in which all Cauchy do converge.

Essentially, a metric space where some Cauchy sequences do not converge can be thought of as “missing points” in the same way the rationals are missing the irrational reals, or $X$ is missing the boundary.

These points are “intrinsically” there, in that they exist in a natural and unique extension of the incomplete space.

---

If we wanted to borrow a word used in abstract algebra, we might use the term “Ideally Convergent.”

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your remark on algebra. Ideals come from "ideale Zahlen", i.e ideal numbers in German which is because they roughly fix the notion of unique factorization which does not exist in all rings but in Dedekind rings the ideals would admit a unique factorization into prime ideals. I'm not sure what your previous paragraph has to do with "ideally convergent". You can form a completion of a ring with respect to an ideal but this involves a categorical limit.

Comment: I’ll delete that section, @QiZhu

Comment: Sorry, I still don‘t understand what you mean by „ideally convergent“.

Comment: Do you know what “ideally” means in English outside mathematics? @QiZhu “Ideally, I’d have a million dollars.” It is not a true statement, but it is one we wish were true. That was the sense of “ideal numbers” to. Ideally, those numbers existed.

Comment: So in both cases, “ideal” is taken to mean “in an ideal world, this would be true.” In an ideal world, the sequence would converge. In an ideal world, the common factor would be a number.

Comment: What kinda question is that, of course I know what „ideal“ means, I just explained the origin of ideals in algebra in my previous comment... Thank you for the explanation, I get what you want to say now (but saying it is a term borrowed from algebra is simply confusing, the only similarity is that both use the word „ideal“). Also „Ideally, I‘d have a million dollars.“ is not only not a true statement, it is not even a statement - it is neither true nor wrong.

Comment: @QiZhu you explained the German origin, and, while a lot of people here have differing levels of English experience. It is one thing to communicate math well in English, but another thing entirely to know what the words mean outside mathematics. I don't know you, so I have no way to know your English skills beyond math. Don't have a cow. The meaning I'm using for "ideal" is the standard English term, not the math term, and under the standard English term, it makes sense to me, so I thought it might be the source of your confusion of my usage.

Comment: 1. Maybe I didn‘t explain well enough, sorry. I thought it was clear why people called them „ideal“ due to my factorization explanation. 2. Your phrasing (including „don‘t have a cow“, like wtf) are simply disrespectful, maybe you didn‘t mean it like that but that‘s the impression it made. 3. As I‘ve explained before, the confusion is that you write that „you borrow the term from abstract algebra“ which might indicate that it has to do with algebra. But that is not the case, you simply use the word „ideal“. But ok, I guess we‘ve understood each other now, so all is fine. Have an ideal day.

Comment: (1) What made them “ideal” in German? They were still “ideal” in the sense of “an ideal world.” They didn’t exist as numbers, but Kummer et al thought they “should, ideally.” The fact that the “ideal” they were reaching for is unique factorization doesn’t negate this use of the meaning of the word. They were “ideal numbers” because in an ideal world, they’d still have unique factorization. They weren’t actual numbers.  (2) You are still having a cow. I wasn’t disrespectful, you just decided to read it that way.

Comment: My god. That's exactly what I was saying. I'm out here, cheers.

Comment: Then I don’t get your original confusion with “ideally converging,” if you understand all this. It is exactly analogous. @QiZhu